# How can I implement a custom progress bar in Android?

Tags: android, progress-bar

I want to implement a custom progress bar that looks like this:

[image: 1]

and I want to be able to do something after progress bar passing each one of that vertical lines and number of vertical lines should be customizable programmatically. Something like play specific sound or display specific Toast or anything.

**Update:**

Lets say, the progress based on time in seconds and the lines are equal numbers of seconds. for example the whole progress is in 40s and lines are in 10th, 20th and 30th seconds.

Comment: What does the progress bar represent? And also, how are you updating the progress bar?

Comment: Thanks for your attention, I did update my question if that could be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the max value of the progress bar:

```
progressBar.setMax(4); // Or whatever number of notches you want
```

**EDIT :** This will sleep for 1000 milliseconds (1 second), and then update the progress bar. It will keep updating until it reaches the max value.

```
private void startProgressThread() {
    new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {

            while (progressBar.getProgress() < progressBar.getMax()) {

                // Wait for 1 second
                Thread.sleep(1000);

                progressBar.post(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {                        
                        progressBar.setProgress(progressBar.getProgress() + 1);

                        // Show your toast or play your sound.
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
                                       "It's been " + progressBar.getProgress() + " seconds.",
                                       Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }

                });

            }

        }

    }).start();
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but the whole progress is specific seconds of the time and the lines are in equal parts base on progress time.

Comment: @MiladNekofar I've updated my answer for you. Is that more like what you want to do? It will update the progress bar each second, and the progress bar will move along the same amount each second.

Comment: Actualy I want to show progress between parts somthing more like [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/s8d3k.png).

Comment: Do you want the progress bar to actually show the divides? Or is that there just to clarify?

Comment: Yes, I want to show all divides, and I want to be able to change their number programmatically.